# Dataflow with beam.dataframe.io.read_fwf : missing Ptransforms

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm facing a problem. I have no clue how to fix it.

I have a pipeline in batch mode. I read a file using the method read_fwf : beam.dataframe.io.read_fwf; However, all following PTransforms are ignored. I wonder why ?

As you can see, my pipeline ended up having 1 step:

[image]

But, my code has the following pipeline :

```
#LOAD FILE RNS
elements = p | 'Load File' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_fwf('gs://my_bucket/files/202009.txt', header=None, colspec=col_definition, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
  
#PREPARE VALUES (BULK INSERT)
Script_Values = elements | 'Prepare Bulk Insert' >> beam.ParDo(Prepare_Bulk_Insert())  
        
#GROUP ALL VALUES
Grouped_Values = Script_Values | 'Grouping values' >> beam.GroupByKey()

#BULK INSERT INTO POSTGRESQL GROUPING BASED
Inserted = Grouped_Values | 'Insert PostgreSQL' >> beam.Map(functionMapInsert)
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Kindly,
Juliano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the fact that, as you can see in the [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/_modules/apache_beam/dataframe/io.html), `beam.dataframe.io.read_fwf` returns a deferred [Beam dataframe](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) representing the contents of the file, not a `PCollection`.

You can embed `DataFrames` in a pipeline and convert between them and `PCollection`s with the help of the functions defined in the [`apache_beam.dataframe.convert`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/apache_beam.dataframe.convert.html#module-apache_beam.dataframe.convert) module.

The SDK documentation provides [an example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) of this setup, fully described in [Github](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_dataframe.py).

I think it is worth value to try the [`DataframeTransform`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.html#apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.DataframeTransform) as well, perhaps it is more suitable for being integrated in the pipeline with the help of a [schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#what-is-a-schema) definition.

In relation with this last suggestion, please, consider reviewing this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806775/how-to-use-pandas-in-apache-beam), especially the answer from @robertwb and the exceptional linked [google slides document](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10XnYgKsTzuvXuQrdt9KtA21l2ifXstWMw19r6_wWpJ0/mobilepresent?slide=id.p), I think it can be helpful.

Comment: Hello, when I put the code here I just copied it incorrectly. Sorry. Unfortunately I still have the problem . I'm not sure if read_fwf supports this kind of stuff. =(

Comment: Hi @JulianoMedeiros. There is no need to apologize, on the contrary, sorry, I give you an answer only thinking in the obvious problem without further dig into the actual one. Please, see my updated answer. Honestly, I never use dataframes with Dataflow, but I hope the information provided is helpful.

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, I'm trying here. As soon as I finish it I will let you know if I make it.
Thank you

Comment: Morning @jccampanero, How are you ? I'm trying to follow the examples.. but until now I didn't make it. I'm not sure where to invoke the method to_pcollection () 
Can you help me,please? Thank you

Comment: I have tried this : Script_Values = to_pcollection(elements) | 'Prepare Bulk Insert' >> beam.ParDo(Prepare_Bulk_Insert())  .. but it didn't work. I got : "Exception has occurred: TypeError 0 has type int, but expected one of: bytes, unicode" =(

Comment: Hi @JulianoMedeiros. I apologize for the late response. I am fine, thank you very much, and you? As I told you in a previous comment, I never used the dataframes API in Dataflow. Any way, I will try to dig into it. Please, I would try several things: first, as the DataFrames API is quite recent, try to deploy a simple example in Dataflow an see how it looks like in GCP. For this purpose, I think the [word count](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_dataframe.py) will be a valid example. Also, I think it is worth value to try ... see next comment

Comment: the [`DataframeTransform`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.html#apache_beam.dataframe.transforms.DataframeTransform) as well, perhaps it is more suitable for being integrated in the pipeline with the help of a schema definition. I came across this [blog entry](https://beam.apache.org/blog/dataframe-api-preview-available/), please, review the `DataFrames as a DSL` section. Regarding the error, can it be caused by the logic implemented in `Prepare_Bulk_Insert()`?

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, All good here, thank you.
`Prepare_Bulk_Insert()` is a very simple method. It just gets the parsed content of read_fwf() and prepares a query. At this stage, the method will build the "values" of the bulk insert: "Insert into table values `(a,b,c),(a,b,c),(a,b,c) ...`" It works fine.  


`Now I have a dobt, Is it wrong to use pandas.read_fwf instead of beam.dataframe.io.read_fwf ? `

I will try now the DataframeTransform and the DataFrames as a DSL. Thank you :)

Comment: I am happy to hear that you are fine. Yes, please, give it a try. I will try to dig into the DataFrames API as well.

Comment: Juliano, please, review this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806775/how-to-use-pandas-in-apache-beam) , especially the answer from @robertwb and the exceptional linked [google slides document](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10XnYgKsTzuvXuQrdt9KtA21l2ifXstWMw19r6_wWpJ0/mobilepresent?slide=id.p), I think it can be helpful.

Comment: I will do it now. Thank you :)